# Differential equation with unusual particular form

Tags: differential

Equation: $y'' - y = (4x + 4)e^x$
The complementary solution is not a problem. However when attempting the particular solution, I run into a problem. Which form do I assume? I have attempted everything from a linear function to a cubic.

Comment: Did you try a polynomial times $e^x$?

Comment: $(ax^2+b)e^x$ seems to work